# AndroidStudio Bug: cannot find AndroidJUnit4.class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing

Today my AndroidStudio is driving me mad. I just wanted to write and `androidTest` for a module I'm working on. But Android Studio keeps Highlighting `InstrumentationRegistry` or `AndroidJUnit4` saying, it cannot find the symbols. 
[image: Default Android Test Image]

This happens on every module I try, even for newly created ones. You may have noticed, that the small green play buttons are at the left, and they actually work! It runs the tests just fine and is debuggable, where I can step into things like `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()`

Because I get no syntax highlighting, code-completion or whatsoever,  this is not an environment I'd like to work in.

Going crazy I asked my co-worker for help. He opened a project on his PC, went into an AndroidTest just to see, that the same is happening for him. Suddenly Android refuses to resolve the `android.support.test.XXX` imports.

I already restarted Android Studio, and my PC.
What is going on there? How can I fix it?

So an example build.gradle looks just like the default:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
```

**UPDATE**: I'm using AndroidStudio Version 3.1.4

Comment: You do not appear to indicate what version of Android Studio you are using. If you are using AS 3.1, try File > Invalidate Caches / Restart.

Comment: Additionally might help: Close AS, delete `.idea` folder in your project, re-import project.

Comment: deleting all .iml files and the .idea folder worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Christopher Please post your comment as answer, so I can accept ;)

Comment: new version of android studio sometimes not able to rebuild the project try
to clean and rebuild project or delete the build folder manually (which is in app folder).